# Can you run the PHP Phrozn static generator from the web?

Tags: php

[Phrozn](http://www.phrozn.info/) is a PHP project that will read Twig, Textile, Markdown, and LESS format files and output them as a static site generator just like the Ruby version of 
  [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)

Phrozn is ran from the command line, I am curious if anyone know if it is possible to run it from a webpage instead of the command line?

If anyone has any experience with this project please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any executable from within a PHP script by using either the system() or exec() commands.  If you wanted to provide a user with a web interface that mimics the command line you could create a page containing a form with whatever options are available to Phozn's command line and have it post that data to a PHP file which would parse the $_POST data and form the equivalent command-line string (ex: "phrozn -l --some_thing -n=somethingelse") and then simply pass that to the system() or exec() function to run it.  If you need to capture the output you can do so and then display that back to the user.

EDIT: Re-read the OP and notice that Phronz is a PHP project run via the CLI.  The above still applies though - you could in theory call a PHP script that runs via the CLI using system() or exec(), although if it's already a PHP project it would seem to make more sense to just edit the source to provide a GUI functionality.  AFAIK you can run any PHP project that's run via the CLI directly via a webpage.